# scrappng in pentaho data integration

Tags: web-scraping, httpclient, pentaho, kettle

I want to scrape the data from the page which is coming after login authentication, i am using http client but only able to get the HTML from the 1st page even after i am passing the URL of the page from where i want data, as it is obvious that i am not able to give username and password for authentication, it is ultimately landing it to login page only, so can somebody explain how and where i can pass my login details for that i will get the HTML of the page from where i want to scrap the data.

Comment: Hi "Working Hard". Maybe you can use two http-steps. The first one authentificates on the login-page the second scaps the data from the URL - maybe the session is the same here .... Just as an idea!

Comment: we have to pass the url through add constant rows, then using HTTP client we have to accept that url which we are passing, so in that page HTTP login and HTTP password is their, so i am trying to give my username and password but it is not accepting, so i am giving username and password at the proper place or i have to do something else that is my question.